# Book cover: put figure next to minipage doesn't work

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, minipage

I am making a cover for a book and have a problem of aligning three blocks together:

1. Some info (this part is more or less okay)
2. Name of a book (has to be centered in the middle but currently more adjusted to a top)
3. Picture for a cover for some reason is not on the same page

Unfortunately, my very unsystematic experience with latex doesn't allow me to find a mistake so I would be very grateful for your comments.

Currently a cover looks like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ paperwidth=300mm, paperheight=210mm, inner=0in, outer=0in, bottom=in, top=in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
%\usepackage[pass]{geometry}% just to show the page margins

\usepackage{pagecolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pagecolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
%\pagecolor{black}
   \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}% adapt widths of minipages to your needs
        {\color{red} This is the place for any info you will put \blindtext}
    \end{minipage}%
%\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[c]% Name of the book
{\color{red} \rotatebox{90}{Monday begins on Saturday}}
\end{minipage}%
%\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%\raggedleft
\begin{figure}
\begin{flushright}% or better \raggedleft see comments below
    \includegraphics[height=200mm]{cover.png}
\end{flushright}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using a float for something that should not float. Includegraphics works fine without the figure env

Comment: @daleif yes you are right, but it doesn't fix the problem, unfortunately

Comment: When I do come covers to be printed I do this: 1. Define the oversized paper to use (important if you have color to edge on the cut down version of the cover as printers often cannot print to edge. 2. Place everything globally on the page using tikz, I often add various guidelines to help. Then you don't need to deal with minipages that does not want to work. I do often use minipages or parboxes to hold the text but use nodes and anchors to place the. Not you'd probably want to reintroduce parindent for the back side text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this solution, with simple tools: I use `tabularx`, thecolume with the text and the column with the image are `X` column, I added a first column containing an invisible rule of length 200mm, and I played with some `\raisebox`es to centre  vertically the image (I had to take one of mine).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[ paperwidth=300mm, paperheight=210mm, hmargin=0in, vmargin=1in, noheadfoot, showframe ]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, , rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pagecolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pagecolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\pagecolor{DarkSlateGrey}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c@{}X |c| >{\raggedleft}X <{\qquad}}%
  \rule[\dimexpr-\textheight +2ex]{0pt}{\textheight} & \color{red} \large This is the place for any info you will put \blindtext &
\qquad\smash{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{%
\makebox[\dimexpr\textheight-3ex]{\huge\bfseries\color{Gold}\raisebox{2.5ex}{Monday begins on Saturday}}}}\qquad
 &\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr1 in-5 mm}{ \includegraphics[height=200mm, valign =t]{paravent}}}
\end{tabularx}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that worked, thank you very much!